# How to list distinct names of cities in SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, select, distinct

I need to find the total number of distinct names of cities being the departure locations for at least one trip. A city is a departure location when it is a departure location of the first leg of a trip.

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT DEPARTURE
FROM TRIPLEG
WHERE LEGNUM = 1;
```

When I test this select statement, the results show all the departure locations (even if a city is mentioned more than once).

How do I make it so that a city name is only displayed once?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTURE
FROM TRIPLEG
WHERE LEGNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use group by

```
SELECT DEPARTURE
FROM TRIPLEG
WHERE LEGNUM = 1
GROUP BY DEPARTURE;
```

Comment: What version of SQL (language) requires a group by? Also, I don't see how this is a useful alternative.

Comment: @JamesAMohler: there is no difference in using `group by` or `distinct`. They both do the same thing here. The group by is  just a bit confusing without an aggregate function

Comment: IF he want to find total number of distinct names I will help